# check parent-child loop function

Tags: java, algorithm, infinite-loop

I'm trying to create a function that can recognize the parent-child loop.
Imagin

> Object A is a parent of Object B
> Object B is a parent of Object C

create a function that can prevent the parent-child loop. the function should give at least two parameters (childName, parentName) and get errors if the relationship creates a loop. in the above example if we pass (A, C) should print or pass string:

> "A is the parent of C"

I know how to create this function(you can provide answer with any language):

```
private static void restrict_ParentChild_Loop(Object A, Object B) throws Exception {
    if (A.parent == null)
        return;
    if (A.parent.equals(B)) {
        throw new Exception("");
    } else {
        restrict_ParentChild_Loop(A.parent, B);
    }
}
```

My main question is about how to provide the right message in the Exception. ("A is the parent of C")

Comment: @user16320675
yes, that is my exact question, how should I create my recursive to send messages with basic inputs?

Comment: use return value of method instead of Exception (otherwise you can use `try`-`catch` but that is *ugly* - Exceptions should NOT be used for control flow or similar)

Comment: @user16320675 this is a good idea, to create two functions and return the value of the recursive function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main question is about how to provide right message in the Exception.

I'm still wondering why that's not the question title itself.

Since this question is likely opinion-based... I'll give my shot?

Your code at:

```java
throw new Exception("");
```

Will throw an `Exception` like this:

```java
java.lang.Exception: At ...
```

So it will be even better if you just tell it what you want it to show in the first place:

```java
throw new Exception(A.parent+" is the parent of "+B.child);
//This throws:
java.lang.Exception: A is the parent of C: At ...
```

Which results in:

```java
private static void restrict_ParentChild_Loop(Object A, Object B) throws Exception {
    if (A.parent == null)
        return;
    if (A.parent.equals(B)) {
        throw new Exception(A.parent+" is the parent of "+B.child);
    } else {
        restrict_ParentChild_Loop(A.parent, B);
    }
}
```